# Compare a filesystem to a dump

Tags: filesystems, backup, dump

Is there a way to compare the current state of the filesystem to that stored in a backup created by `dump`?

I recently had some major corruption in the filesystem and my most recent backup is from several months ago. I want to compare the two in order to get an idea of how much was corrupted and hopefully see how much has changed since the backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `restore` command. It has a switch, `-C` which looks like what you're looking for.

*excerpt from [restore man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/restore)*

```
-C     This  mode allows comparison of files from a dump.  Restore reads the 
       backup and compares its contents with files present on the disk. It 
       first changes its working directory to the root of the filesystem that
       was dumped and compares  the  tape  with the files in its new current 
       directory. See also the -L flag described below.
```